# Memory allocation/deallocation for pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, free, calloc

I have simple socket communicate function:

```
int communicate( const char * tx, char * rx, int bufSize , char * inetAddr, int port )
{
    if (!sockInitialised) initSock();

    if (sockInitialised)
    {
        SOCKET s;
        struct sockaddr_in server;

        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inetAddr);
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( port );

        if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            BOOST_LOG_SEV(getDefLg(), debug) << "Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError();
        } else
        {
            if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
            {
                puts("connect error");
                return 1;
            } else
            {
                int l =strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA ");

                char* dtx ;
                dtx = (char*) calloc(sizeof(char),strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA "));

                sprintf(dtx,"DATA %s",tx);

                if( send(s , dtx , strlen(dtx) , 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                } else
                {

                    int recv_size = 0;
                    if((recv_size = recv(s , rx , bufSize , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        puts("recv failed");
                    } else
                    {
                        rx[recv_size] = '\0';
                    }
                }
                free(dtx);
            }
        }
    } else return 1;


}
```

I have error on line

```
free(dtx);
```

Error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
---------------------------
Debug Error!


    HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#1497) at 0x057D26F8.
    CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.


    (Press Retry to debug the application)
    ---------------------------
    Abort   Retry   Ignore   
    ---------------------------
```

What is wrong with `calloc` and `free` in this code?

Comment: `calloc(sizeof(char),strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA "))` isn't big enough. it doesn't account for the terminating null-char.

Comment: Don't use C compatibility features in C++ if you are not interfacing with actual C code. In particular, do not use C strings, pointers, malloc and friends.

Comment: And what I could use instead of calloc?

Comment: In addition, don't even attempt to think that in TCP the number of bytes you send in one `send` is the number of bytes the other side gets in one `recv`.

Comment: I suggest you read a good introductory text on C++. In this case just std::string is sufficient, but you really really want to read a good book before going any further.

Comment: I had old peace of code in C I decided to use in C++ project. I know about std:string, but decided not to change code I have. But why it is bad practice to use C things in C++? There so many useful functions on internet in C you can just copy ant paste to your project

Comment: @user1501700 compile them as C and link to your project. C and C++ are different languages and code which is valid C may be invalid C++, or even worse, be valid but give different results.

Comment: @MattMcNabb "I had old peace of code in C I decided to use in C++ project." If its C code, compile it with a C compiler and if there apr problems, tag any questions about it with the C tag. "There so many useful functions on internet in C you can just copy ant paste to your project". Doesn't look like these incredibly useful functions have done your project any good. See, it crashes and makes you waste your time asking questions on SO. So far, evidence against using C functions found on internet is compelling.

Comment: @nm I think you mis-tagged me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate `strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA ")` bytes for concatenation of those two strings - where is the byte for zero terminator? Use `strlen(tx)+strlen("DATA ")+1`.